# A user-movable dot on a map view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

What would be the best way to place a dot (a custom png) on an MKMapView, and allow the user to move the dot around the map. Additionally, when the finger is released, the map should center on the dot...

Are the any techniques which could make this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check out the [MKOverlayView class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html), as this should help you out with drawing the custom png.

You could perhaps subclass this class and override the instance methods `– touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `– touchesEnded:withEvent` and `– touchesCancelled:withEvent:` to handle the user input?